# In case of ServiceStack.Redis what are default values for RedisPoolSize,RedisPoolTimeoutSeconds

Tags: redis, servicestack

In case of ServiceStack.Redis what are default values for redisPoolSize, RedisPoolTimeoutSeconds and default port.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume you are interested in the connection pool, as opposed to the buffer pool; for which there are two pools, a READ pool and a WRITE pool. They are created based on the number of hosts of each type multiplied by the `PoolSizeMultiplier` which defaults to 10.

- The default Redis Write Pool Size is the number of Read/Write Redis Hosts * the default PoolSizeMultiplier = 10. [See line #131](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis/blob/1bcfef15c565c9945cc340aa8f9aa8d3a3d01130/src/ServiceStack.Redis/PooledRedisClientManager.cs)
- The default Redis Read Pool Size is the number of Read Only Redis Hosts * the default PoolSizeMultiplier = 10. [See line #132](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis/blob/1bcfef15c565c9945cc340aa8f9aa8d3a3d01130/src/ServiceStack.Redis/PooledRedisClientManager.cs)
- The default `RedisPoolTimeoutSeconds` is 2 seconds (2000 milliseconds). [See line #140](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis/blob/1bcfef15c565c9945cc340aa8f9aa8d3a3d01130/src/ServiceStack.Redis/PooledRedisClientManager.cs).
- The default port is the Redis default of 6379.

---

- The default [Buffer Pool Size](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis/blob/cb1e8f1d1bedee1f443ad17420f530da8d8a1e5b/src/ServiceStack.Redis/BufferPool.cs) is 1000, with a Buffer Length of 1450.